# Whether a space is compact, if all functions are bounded

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a paracompact Hausdorff space. It is easy to see the following statement.

> If $X$ is compact, then every continuous function is bounded.

**Does the converse hold?** If every function on $X$ is bounded, then is $X$ compact?

The reason why I assume $X$ to be paracompact Hausdorff is the existence of "enough" number of functions. Namely, I wanted to make use of a partition of unity, but my attempt has not succeeded yet. So feel free to remove the assumptions, if you want.

Comment: You're talking about boundedness without a metric space anywhere in sight?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comments. [Spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146) finds no counterexamples. (For functions into $\Bbb R$; i.e., $X$ pseudocompact.)

Comment: W.S. Watson, *Pseudocompact metacompact spaces are compact*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A space $X$ is said to be **pseudocompact** if every (real-valued) function on $X$ is bounded.
- A paracompact space is always metacompact.

Thorem (Scott, Förster, Watson) Pseudocompact metacompact spaces are compact.

Applying it, we can conclude that a pseudocomact and paracomact space is compact.